# Update Many using $(update)

Tags: mongodb

```
db.getCollection('test').updateMany(
    {}, //match all
    [{
        $set: {
            players: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    [], //Creating new array for all the documents
                    [{ //Adding these values
                        "player_name": "$player_name",
                        "book_id": new ObjectId()
                    }]
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

When I try to do `updateMany` on this, it throws syntax error on `$set` braces.

Is it not possible with mongo version 4.2.8?

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: `update` works. `updateMany` throws unexpected braces at last but one line.

Comment: @Gibbs remove the `[]` from the update query before the `$set` operator, its not a valid update object

Comment: is `4.2.8` the version of your mongo *shell* ? otherwise upgrade the `mongo` to the latest version. Some version might not support the update pipeline for .updateMany, you can use .update with the option `multi: true` instead

Comment: @KunalMukherjee That's perfectly valid with the version which I am using.

Comment: @thammada.ts `multi:true` does the job, Thanks. Could you tell me the problem with `updateMany` - mainly wanted to know whether it is supported or not. If supported, what's wrong with the syntax? 4.2.8 is the server version.

Comment: The issue is with the version of your mongo `shell`. The server should support it.

Comment: @thammada.ts I am using robo3T to connect to the server. 4.4 is in beta still. Which version you are recommending?

Comment: It seems the embedded mongo shell in the latest version (as of today) of Robo3T still doesn't support update pipeline for .updateMany if you install the latest version of `mongo` shell locally and use that, it should work though.